# Random output at last iteration for reversing an integer

Tags: java, while-loop, integer

I am trying to reverse an int,following is my code

```
int num = 1534236469,temp=num;

while (temp != 0) {
    digit = temp % 10;
    temp = temp / 10;
    sum = ((sum * 10) + digit);
}
```

At the 2nd final iteration i get 964632435,which is as expected,but at the last iteration out of nowhere i get 1056389759..

Can someone help me understand what is happening here?

Comment: Looks like int overflow, no?  The largest int allowed is 2147483647

Comment: nope its within [-2^31, 2^31 - 1]

Comment: No, not as the while loop is iterating and changing the value of the number. What happens if you use BigInteger or long?

Comment: the req is within the int range,so its customary,got it anyway,tnx!

Comment: With long, your code works, no? And what do you mean by your statement above, about "req"?

Comment: it works for long,req is requirement.

Comment: just curious on how the loop works once it exceeds the range of the variable

Comment: @SanthoshNS  The loop works normally since it is  based on a valid integer which is being constantly divided by 10.  The problem is that you start with a valid integer but when you reversed it overflows because the original value ends in 9.  The reversed result is a separate value from the one being used in the loop so the loop is unaffected by the conversion.  If the original value ended in `1` it would work as written.  If it ended with `2` it would overflow (and  in that case become negative).

Answer (score 0):

It  is definitely int overflow.

```
int num = 1534236469,temp=num;
int sum = 0;
while (temp != 0) {
    int digit = temp % 10;
    temp = temp / 10;
    sum = ((sum * 10) + digit);
    System.out.printf("%,14d  %,14d%n",sum, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
}
```

prints

```
             9   2,147,483,647
            96   2,147,483,647
           964   2,147,483,647
         9,646   2,147,483,647
        96,463   2,147,483,647
       964,632   2,147,483,647
     9,646,324   2,147,483,647
    96,463,243   2,147,483,647
   964,632,435   2,147,483,647
 1,056,389,759   2,147,483,647
```

Compare the left to the int maximum on the right. What happens when you compute the last value and multiply `964,632,435` by `10`?

Extract from the [Java Language Specification - multiplication operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se18/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.1)

"*If an integer multiplication overflows, then the result is the low-order bits of the
mathematical product as represented in some sufficiently large two's-complement
format. As a result, if overflow occurs, then the sign of the result may not be the
same as the sign of the mathematical product of the two operand values*"

Here is an example.

```
long v = 964_632_435;
v *= 10;
System.out.println("long value * 10 = " + v);
v = v&Integer.MAX_VALUE; // mask off high order 33 bits in the long
                         // remember that largest int value is 31 bit value
                         // of all ones or x7FFF_FFFF
System.out.println("long after mask = " + v);
System.out.println("long adding 1   = " + (v+1));
```

prints

```
long value * 10 = 9646324350
long after mask = 1056389758
long adding 1   = 1056389759
```

And one final example using bit strings.

```
String bits = Long.toBinaryString(9646324350L);
System.out.println("long value = "  + bits);
int len = bits.length();

bits = bits.substring(len-31, len);
System.out.println("low order 31 bits = " + bits);
int val = Integer.parseInt(bits,2);
System.out.println("Overflow value = " + val);
```

prints

```
long value = 1000111110111101110011101001111110
low order 31 bits = 0111110111101110011101001111110
Overflow value = 1056389758  (before adding 1)
```

Comment: Compare the left to the int maximum on the right. What happens when you compute the last value and multiply 964,632,435 by 10?    --- that is the part i am curious about..

Comment: @SanthoshNS Please see my updated answer.